# Managing the creation and update of work items in TFS 2018 API

Tags: c#, tfs

We're migrating to TFS 2018 and we currently use the c# TFS 2013 API to connect to TFS and create and update Work Items, I'm trying to find the best approach to migrate the use of the 2013 API to the new 2018 API.
Currently, the process creates a blank Work Item via the NewWorkItem() method of the WorkItemStore and it's fields are filled in different parts of the job extension based on some rules and we call the validate() method of the Work Item to check if values entered are ok. Then the relationships are built, between parent and child (PBI and Task), and everything is submitted at the same time using the BatchSave method from the WorkItemStore.

I'm trying to find the best way to replicate this in the TFS 2018 API, and started using the WorkItemTrackingHttpClient, more specifically the CreateWorkItemAsync method for creating a WorkItem and specifying the fields through the JsonPatchDocument, is this the best approach or should we use a different one? The problem with this approach is that we have to keep submitting the changes in the values of the fields of the WorkItem (different fields are set in different parts of the job extension) as opposed to set all the fields of the WorkItem, setting its parent or child, and then submitting all at once.

```
//TFS 2013:
var workItem = Store.Projects[TeamProject].WorkItemTypes[workItemType].NewWorkItem();
//field assignment
workItem.Fields[CoreField.AssignedTo].Value = Store.TeamProjectCollection.AuthorizedIdentity.DisplayName;
//field validation
 workItem.Validate().Cast<Field>().Any(field => field.ReferenceName == referenceName)
//link creation
parent.WorkItemLinks.Add(new WorkItemLink(Store.WorkItemLinkTypes[Fields.RequirementToTaskRelationName].ForwardEnd, childrenId));
//batch save after everything done
Store.BatchSave(new[] { parentWorkItem, taskWorkItem });

//TFS 2018:
//work item creation
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
var workItem = witClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(document, TeamProject, workItemType).Result;

//fields assignment
var document = new JsonPatchDocument();

AddFieldValue(document, CoreFieldReferenceNames.Title, GetHtmlFieldValue(false, Event.Title));
```

Comment: _"is this the best approach or should we use a different one?"_ - it would be better if you reformulated your question to be more specific, as currently it's overly broad and asking for opinions, rather than asking for a solution to a particular problem.